# Rails: why time datatype start at 1/1/2000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a column that I only want to store time (hour, minute, second). for example here is one migration:

```
add_column :products, :start_hour, :time
```

When I insert to database `start_hour` always start with `1/1/2000` for example: `2000-01-01 01:19:00 +0700`. Please explain for me why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no time-of-day class in Ruby or Rails so ActiveRecord represents `time` columns with datetime/timestamp classes.

If you look inside the database without any of the ActiveRecord, Rails, or Ruby noise in the way, you'll see an `HH:MM:SS` time-of-day value. But when ActiveRecord pulls a `time` out of the database, it sets the date component to 2000-01-01 because a datetime has to have a date and AR picks that one.

Any time you work with a `start_hour` in Ruby you'll have to ignore the date component.

Comment: thanks. why rails choose "1/1/2000" not a base time 1970 for example. Are there any reasons here. thanks.

Comment: Because most of the Rails devs weren't alive in 1970? Seriously though, there's probably no particular reason, they just needed a date and 2000-01-01 looked good.

Answer (score -1):

The difference between formats stored in your DB have nothing to do with Rails and everything to do with your database.  Date or Time formats are only 'valid' within your application, not within the database -more simply they are only responsible for the way time objects are displayed to your users and will not affect the way data is stored.  Your best bet is to save the records as time objects and then use rails helpers to present the data to your users in a meaningful way with such methods as `strptime` etc.

Comment: database has `time` datatype. that means time not only application datatype.