# Why does Rails store time format data as UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime

There is table data that is generic, and therefore only requires time as data (no date).  Thus the data type is saved to postgresql as `time`.

But then this idiosyncracy pops up

```
> @day_schedules.first
=> #<Schedule id: 17, start_time: "2000-01-01 06:00:00"
```

Then,

```
> @day_schedules.first.start_time
=> 2000-01-01 06:00:00 UTC
```

So this data is in fact *wrong* if one wants to compare data with `datetime` data types,   say...

```
@interruptions[0].pause
=> Sat, 18 Mar 2017 07:35:18 CET +01:00
```

as now we are comparing a UTC to CET...  How can the `time` be handled as the given value "06:00:00" but for the `CET +01:00` time zone?

Comment: Everything should be UTC inside the database because that's the Rails Way. Your `time` (actually `time without time zone`) will be just a time-of-day inside the database. There is no [time-of-day class in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42539230/479863), hence the `2001-01-01` date in your `start_time`. Time zones may or may not be applied in Ruby-land. I'd guess that you'd have a better time doing the time work inside the database (where time-of-day is a real thing) and just pulling timestamps out.

Comment: If I am not wrong you are trying to compare two timestamps where one is in UTC and other is in CET. It can be thought of as a standard that on the server, you should handle/store everything as UTC and then modify it accordingly when sending back in the browser or in the backend itself.

In this case I will suggest to convert the other time zone to UTC and then take do the calculations. Does that helps?

Comment: The trick was in understanding that the data is stored in UTC, but date time and time behave differently when calling them. So the solution lies in using a chain command to relate items on a consistent basis `start_time.in_time_zone`  The **in_time_zone** suffix brought all comparisons in line.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon Mu's comment.  Rails stores time in UTC as the default but this can be changed if you want all formats coinciding with a different local.  I must warn it is normally considered best practice to remain in UTC but if you're looking to dabble you can:

First run `rake time:zones:all` to see the available timezones you can set in the Rails config.  Then if you want to have Rails use one of these timezones you can set it as the following in your application.rb or initializer file:

## application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

Then you can also add the following line below the time_zone that will set ActiveRecord to store your data in the same format as the new timezone you've just set:

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```